# Animation only renders one frame

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, animation

I am trying to render an animation but it only renders one frame and stops right before its done rendering the second frame. It always stops with two tiles remaining. My frame range is 1 to 140 and 24fps. My step is also set to 1. Preview range is turned of and my file format is ffmpeg video  with mpeg-4 as the container.I am using my gpu to render and am using cycles. I have tried Reinstalling and repairing blender but that didn't fix it.Any help would be really appreciated.

Here is the render Properties.
[image]
Here is the output properties
[image]

Comment: can you add an image of the render properties and output properties

Comment: There you go pal

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. My samples were just too high. Putting it below fifty fixed it.